# Refresh Database/server every 60 minutes

Tags: database, server

How can I keep the server active and update the database every 60 minutes or after some specific time period ?

I am working on a project where the website updates the database per user.

If the user add something to the cart, the stock gets updated.

But if the user does not checkout within 60 minutes, the product gets removed from the cart and the stock gets updated again.

Now the problem : If no one visits the website for say 2 hours, how should I update the server/database ??

In short, how do I keep the server live without the website being visited by any user.
I want to set a timer for the server.

I hope someone understands what I am asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement time scheduler or a listener which will run at in every 60 minutes, In time scheduler you implement the update database logic.

Comment: yes, that is what exactly I want to do, the question is how do I do it ??

Comment: which language and framework  are you using in server side (e.g-> java, Spring etc)?

Comment: I am using PHP
But I got it solved by using timestamp for each and every item.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a background service to perform this task or if you want it to happen through application only, in that case  you can use scheduler like **Quartz**.

Check

JAVA http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/

.NET https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/